# Is this code considered secure and dose it pose a vulnerability threat?

Tags: solidity

I am very new to solidity and am wondering if the code below would be considered ok on the mainnet.  The idea is that the manger can set the donation address and then users can send money to that address.  One concern is that the donation function can be called before the donationAddress is set.  Is this a problem even if i am immediately deploying and adding the address?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
contract Donate {

    address public donationAddress;

    address public manager;
    
    function Donate() public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }

    function donation() public payable{
        donationAddress.transfer(this.balance);
    }

    function setCroissantAddr(address adr) public restricted {
        donationAddress = adr;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using very old version of Solidity. To minimize the risk, use atleast `^0.5.0;`, which brings `construstor` keyword where your constructor no need to have the same name as your contract name.